# Skip the program-made changes in valueChanges for FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a form to register an event, I ask for a date, time and if it recurs (daily, weekly, monthly or none at all).

I have also set up another input for the user to specify when that recurrence ends. The problem is that there are two ways of "ending that recurrence". I have a "# of repetitions" (in case i.e. you want to repeat that event weekly for two weeks), but I also have a `datepicker` in case you want to specify the ending date (i.e you want it to repeat daily until September 1st).

When one of the inputs's value changes I trigger a function to update the other, so it keeps consistent

For example, if I specify that I want it to repeat daily and I set 5 times, then my datepicker would show the date 5 days away from the original date and vise versa.

The problem is that, since I have a listener for changes on both inputs, when the user changes one, I change the value on the other one (programmatically) and that triggers the `valueChanges` on that input as well, so it keeps going back and forth.

After all this introduction, is there any way you may suggest to difference between a "user-made" change and the one I do on `inputValueChanges` ?

Comment: probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/41957846/5031771

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you update a form control value with [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalue) you can set the emitEvent option to false. This will stop the valueChanges from firing on the change.

```
yourControl.setValue(newValue, { emitEvent: false });
```